# entire page moves up when i click menu bottom tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the following code works fine
ERROR
 - when i click the last tag in menu the entire page move to top how to resolve the error

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Blueprint: Vertical Icon Menu</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leftmenu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flaticon.css" />
    <style>
        body {position: relative;font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;    color: #47a3da;}
        body, html { font-size: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
        a {text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover {color: #000;}
        #header{height: 90px;width: 100%;background-color: #B9F5BB;}
        #footer{height: 50px;width: 100%;background-color: #FDD5CB;}
        .dis123{width:75%;float:left; height: 500px;background-color:#DCEEE3; text-align: left; }
        .postleftmen{width:25%;float:left;color:#f0f0f0;}
        div.subcte456{color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        Head
    </div>
    <div class="postleftmen">
        <ul class="cbp-vimenu">
            <li><a href="#" >select category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-smart" onClick="mob();">mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-pc6" onClick="ele();">electronics&nbsp;&&nbsp;computer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-car95" onClick="veh();">vehicle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-livingroom6" onClick="hme();">home&nbsp;&&nbsp;furniture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-dog50" onClick="pet();">pets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-cd" onClick="bok();">books,&nbsp;cd&nbsp;&&nbsp;hobbies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-black276" onClick="clo();">clothing&nbsp;&&nbsp;accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-baby23" onClick="kid();">kids&nbsp;&&nbsp;baby</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-bicycle14" onClick="spo();">sport&nbsp;&&nbsp;health</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-tools6" onClick="ser();">service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-businessman221" onClick="job();">jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-house111" onClick="rel();">real&nbsp;estate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dis123" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
        <div class="subcte456" style="position:fixed;width:75%;height:60%;background-color: #FDD5CB;margin:0 auto;">
            sanoj

            <div id="mobi" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" ><a href="#">mobile phones</a></div>
            <div id="elec" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >electronics</div>
            <div id="vehi" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >vehicles</div>
            <div id="home" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >home</div>
            <div id="pets" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >pets</div>
            <div id="book" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >books</div>
            <div id="clot" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >clothing</div>
            <div id="kids" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >kids</div>
            <div id="spor" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >sport</div>
            <div id="serv" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >service</div>
            <div id="jobs" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >jobs</div>
            <div id="real" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >real estate</div>

        </div></div>
    <div style="clear:both"> </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
    <script>
        function mob() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('mobi').style.display = "block";
        }
        function ele() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('elec').style.display = "block";
        }
        function veh() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('vehi').style.display = "block";
        }
        function hme() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('home').style.display = "block";
        }
        function pet() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('pets').style.display = "block";
        }
        function bok() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('book').style.display = "block";
        }
        function clo() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('clot').style.display = "block";
        }
        function kid() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('kids').style.display = "block";
        }
        function spo() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('spor').style.display = "block";
        }
        function ser() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('serv').style.display = "block";
        }
        function job() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('jobs').style.display = "block";
        }
        function rel() {
            hidemenus();
            document.getElementById('real').style.display = "block";
        }

        function hidemenus() {
            document.getElementById('mobi').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('elec').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('vehi').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('home').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('pets').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('book').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('clot').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('kids').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('spor').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('serv').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('jobs').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('real').style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

WHAT I NEED IS

- when i click the last one in menu it should display the result without moving to top of the page 
  OR
  Do i need create scroll bar for menu

Comment: Add `return false;` at the end of each `onClick` attribute

Comment: @Populus but already i have a value for onclick how to enter another value

Comment: `onclick="mob(); return false;"`

Comment: @Populus it works but check the last on in menu i still get error in last menu tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

```
<a href="#" class="flaticon-house111" onClick="return rel();">real&nbsp;estate</a>

function rel() {
    hidemenus();
    document.getElementById('real').style.display = "block";
    return false; // <-- will prevent the anchor # link from trigerring
}
```

And repeat for all your links and functions

Comment: Incomplete answer. You will also need to change the `onclick` attribute to something like `onclick="return rel()"`

Comment: @LucLaverdure i found the solution t itsems the rel is registred word in html so i changed rel to est and now it works

Comment: I was just about to say that :) @LucLaverdure you should mention that (and rename `rel`) in your answer for posterity

Answer (score 1):

And alternative (and IMO better) answer.

The `return false` method is not W3C compliant (as in it's undocumented), but it's been working this way for ages so we do it. The "Proper" way is to use the event object:

```
<a href="#" onclick="rel(event)">real estate</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function rel(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // This prevents the a tag (link) to act as like a link, which would no
    hidemenus();
    document.getElementById('real').style.display = "block";
}
```

And actually there is a little bit of optimization you can perform here:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showmenu(event)" data-menu="real">real estate</a>

function showmenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // This prevents the a tag (link) to act as like a link, which would no
    hidemenus();
    document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("data-menu")).style.display = "block";
}

// This works for IE9 and above
function hidemenus() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_list");
    for (var i in elements) {
        if (elements[i] instanceof HTMLElement) {
            elements[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

This way, we don't need to define a separate click handler for each link. Note that `event.target` is the `HTMLElement` object that the user clicked on, which in this case is the link.

The `hidemenus()` function I provided also removes a need to have hardcoded functionality. The reason for the `elements[i] instanceof HTMLElement` check is because `getElementsByClassName` sometimes throws in the length of the array in there, which will break the code.

Fiddle with full code: http://jsfiddle.net/g4qvtod2/1/

An even more advanced way to do this is to attach event listeners to the link dynamically using `addEventListener`, you may attempt that as an exercise.