# How can I make a fixed vertical nav bar float to the top when the window shrinks?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The vertical nav css I am currently using:

```
.vertical-nav {
     position: fixed;
     top: 105px; /* distance to the top of the menu div from the top of the page */
     width:130px; /* width of the menu div */
     height: auto;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 2px solid #0000FF; /* border width, type and color*/
     border-radius: 10px; /* border-radius */         
     background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); /* Menu background color with opacity - delete if not required */
}

// Element with the CSS attached
<div class="sidebar-nav vertical-nav"></div>
```

Currently, the vertical nav bar on the left side of the page stays fixed when I make my window smaller which makes it a bit awkward for the user. Like a bootstrap navbar, I would like the navbar to float to the top when the user adjusts the window.

Any ideas?

Actual code:

```
 <div class="sidebar-nav vertical-nav">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Sidebar menu</span>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav demo">
          <li>
            <center><label>FILTER</label></center>
          </li>
        </br>
          <li class="active"><center><input type="checkbox"/>  1</center></li>
          </br>
          <li class="active"><center><input type="checkbox"/>  2</center></li>
          </br>
          <li class="active"><center><input type="checkbox"/> 3</center></li>
          </br>
          <li class="active"><center><input type="checkbox"/>  4</center></li>
          </br>
          <li class="active"><center><input type="checkbox"/>  5</center></li>
          </br>
          <li class="active"><center><input type="checkbox"/>  6</center></li>
          </br>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">7</a></li>
          </br>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">8</a></li>


          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">Reviews <span class="badge">1,118</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771605/entire-page-moves-up-when-i-click-menu-bottom-tag/25772312#25772312       use the code given there you will find some thing usefull

Comment: boostrap one doesn't float away, it changes from list view to menu view but it still fixed and of the same size.

Comment: Guessing there is no CSS to fix this?

Comment: You put your styles for the large viewport in a min-width media query and BEFORE that you put your styles for the small viewport outside of a media query

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

```
position:fixed;
```

can't be moved so you trying using

```
margin-top: 0px;
```

add

```
margin-top: 0px;
```

Comment: This is the exact same as my code? You just changed the distance of the vertical-nav bar from the top.

Comment: The only changes that I see is "top: 0px".

Comment: then explain what you need

Comment: Currently, the vertical navigation bar is fixed on the left hand side, so that when you scroll down, it will remain in the window. However, due to its fixed nature, when you collapse the window (adjust the window smaller), the navigation bar stays in the same location. Normal bootstrap navbar will float to the top for better formatting and accessibility when the window is shrunk. Is there a way to keep the fixed nav bar but have it go to the top of the page when the window is adjusted?

Comment: @simonzhu i got your problem can you post full code so that i can find error

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to change styles automatically depending on the browser media features, such as width, height, and color like...

```
    <style>
.vertical-nav {
         position: fixed;
         top: 105px; /* distance to the top of the menu div from the top of the page */
         width:130px; /* width of the menu div */
         height: auto;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 5px;
         border: 2px solid #0000FF; /* border width, type and color*/
         border-radius: 10px; /* border-radius */         
         background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); /* Menu background color with opacity - delete if not required */
    }
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .vertical-nav {
        top: 0;
    }
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Idea sounds good. But ust tested it. It doesn't seem work? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I suggest sharing your code using http://jsbin.com/. So that I can have a look once

Comment: i think my code is working. have a look at it once http://jsbin.com/fepibo/1/edit
slide the output section to resize the window

Comment: Nope. just tested it. still does not work. If you collapse the width of the window, you can still see the navbar fixed in that position. Its just a bit difficult to see on jsbin.com. I tried it on my code but still does not seem to work =(

Comment: Nope. I guess it might not be possible. The functionality works if I remove the vertical-nav from: <div class="sidebar-nav vertical-nav">. But then the vertical-nav bar no longer is fixed.

Comment: Please let me know if anyone still has any ideas!